# Signal for QSerialPort is not shown on list

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, signals, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator 4.8.0, Qt 5.12.0 , language is C++, and OS is windows7.

I trying to connect a signal to catch an information comes from serial device.

The syntax is ;

```
QObject::connect(&arduino,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(serial_received()));
```

The signal is working and catching the data... No problem on working...

But.... I couldnt see the readyRead signal on the list while I'm writing the code...

[image: Here is the screenshot]

What is the problem ?

Comment: Maybe trying the "modern" syntax for connecting signal and slots: `QObject::connect(&arduino,&YourArduinoClass::readyRead,this,&Foo::serial_received);` will give better completion suggestions

Comment: Yes you are right... The new syntax must be like this...
connect(&arduino,&QIODevice::readyRead,this,&MainWindow::serial_received);

Comment: You should type QObject, not Qobject. The editor warns you that the Qobject is an undeclared variable, so it can not give you the functions list.